# find index of row element in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

If you have a df:

```
  apple   banana   carrot    
a   1       2        3
b   2       3        1
c   0       0        1
```

To find the index for the columns where a cell is equal to 0 is `df[df['apple']==0].index`
but can you transpose this so you find the index of row c where it is 0?

Basically I need to drop the columns where c==0 and would like to do this in one line by row rather than by each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If want test row `c` and get all columns if `0`:

```
c = df.columns[df.loc['c'] == 0]
print (c)
Index(['apple', 'banana'], dtype='object')
```

---

If want test all rows:

```
c1 = df.columns[df.eq(0).any()]
print (c1)
Index(['apple', 'banana'], dtype='object')
```

---

If need remove columns if `0` in any row:

```
df = df.loc[:, df.ne(0).all()]
print (df)
   carrot
a       3
b       1
c       1
```

**Detail**/**explanation**:

First compare all values of `DataFrame` by [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) (`!=`):

```
print (df.ne(0))
   apple  banana  carrot
a   True    True    True
b   True    True    True
c  False   False    True
```

Then get all rows if [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) `True` rows:

```
print (df.ne(0).all())
apple     False
banana    False
carrot     True
dtype: bool
```

Last filter by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
print (df.loc[:, df.loc['c'].ne(0)])
   carrot
a       3
b       1
c       1
```

If need test only `c` row solution is similar, only first select `c` row by `loc` and omit `all`:

```
df = df.loc[:, df.loc['c'].ne(0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, `df.T[df.T['c']==0]`